# Passed Value from VF page to extended controller resetting to default value

Tags: apex-param

Ok so I know that you can simply pass value from the VF page to controller by setting up a variable in the controller and assinging to the value attribute in the field on the VF page but in my case, it is not passing that value for some odd reason.

VF Code:

```
<apex:column styleClass="actionColumn" headerValue="Calculate">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Save" styleClass="actionLink" status="addBundleStatus" action="{!SaveBundle}" rerender="opportunityDetail" >
                        <apex:param name="selectedBundleId" value="{!bundle.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedBundleId}" />
                        <apex:param name="packQuantityValue" value="{!bundle.Pack_Quantity__c}"  assignTo="{!packQuantityValue}" />
                        <apex:param name="discountValue" value="{!bundle.Discount__c}"  assignTo="{!discountValue}" />
                    </apex:commandLink>
                    <apex:actionStatus id="addBundleStatus">
                        <apex:facet name="start">
                          <apex:image value="/img/loading.gif"/>
                        </apex:facet>
                     </apex:actionStatus>    
                </apex:column>                    
                <apex:column headerValue="Discount">
                    <apex:inputText value="{!bundle.Discount__c}"  id="dis" onChange="document.getElementById('{!$Component.hiddenDis}').value=this.value;alert(document.getElementById('{!$Component.hiddenDis}').value);" />
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!inputValue}" id="hiddenDis"/>
                </apex:column>
```

Controller Code:

```
public PageReference SaveBundle()
{    
    System.debug('selectedBundleId: ' + selectedBundleId);
    System.debug('packQuantityValue: ' + packQuantityValue);
    System.debug('discountValue: ' + discountValue);
    System.debug('inputValue ************************: ' + inputValue);
}
```

So the alert shows the value that I enter in the input field but the System.debug statement in the logs shows nothing. It is assigned on the page but disappears in the controller.
Also this is from my UAT (sandbox) environment, the same scenario works fine in my Dev environment.

Comment: I have faced similar issue when passing id to controller using apex:param. I tried setting the name of the apex:param same as value. EX:  <apex:param name="{!bundle.Id}" value="{!bundle.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedBundleId}"

Comment: Those params are seperate. I'm just talking about the inputValue variable!

Comment: Sorry you didn't mentioned which variable is not getting passed in the question. I assume inputValue is not getting passed to Controller.

Comment: I want to ask you just out of curiosity. Why cant you directly use bundle.Id,bundle.Pack_Quantity__c & bundle.Discount__c fields directly in controller instead of selectedBundleId,packQuantityValue & discountValue

Comment: Also tell me what value are you expecting in "inputValue"? Because i cant see any code where you are assigning any value to it.

Comment: You can ignore the parameters electedBundleId,packQuantityValue & discountValue. All of these need to be passed based on the value that user inputs in the fields so that is why I can't use those variables.
inputValue is expecting a user input value from the inputText field

Comment: So as you can see I assign the hidden field value in the onchange attribute of the inputText field through JS but this change is not reflected in the inputValue variable in the controller.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but `inputValue` won't be passed to the controller until some action method is invoked (and where inputValue is part of the form (or explicit actionRegion; simply entering the value in id="dis" won't cause it to transmit to the controller

Comment: all this is inside a form tag and is submitted on the "Save" command link.